# HIghcharts crosshair label draggable

Tags: javascript, highcharts, draggable

Is it possible to make a crosshair label draggable? So that user can move with the mouse the crosshair label away from the x-axis.

[image]

JS fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/qb2uee9r/1/

```
$.getJSON('https://www.highcharts.com/samples/data/aapl-c.json', function (data) {
// Create the chart
Highcharts.stockChart('container', {

    chart: {
        marginRight: 50
    },
    rangeSelector: {
        selected: 1
    },

    title: {
        text: 'AAPL Stock Price'
    },

    xAxis: {
        crosshair: true
    },

    yAxis: {
        opposite: true,
        labels: {
            align: 'left',
            format: '{value:.2f}',
            y: 6,
            x: 2
        }
    },

    series: [{
        name: 'AAPL',
        data: data,
        tooltip: {
            valueDecimals: 2
        }
    }]
});
});
```

Comment: check https://highcharts.uservoice.com/forums/55896-highcharts-javascript-api and post your idea

Comment: Highcharts doesn't support that functionality.

Comment: Any plugin or anybody who implemented something like this?